# In Coq, How to construct an element of 'sig' type

Tags: types, casting, coq, subtype

With a simple inductive definition of a type `A`:

```
Inductive A: Set := mkA : nat-> A.

(*get ID of A*)
Function getId (a: A) : nat := match a with mkA n => n end.
```

And a subtype definition:

```
(* filter that test ID of *A* is 0 *)
Function filter (a: A) : bool := if (beq_nat (getId a) 0) then true else false.

(* cast bool to Prop *)
Definition IstrueB (b : bool) : Prop := if b then True else False.

(* subtype of *A* that only interests those who pass the filter *)
Definition subsetA : Set := {a : A | IstrueB (filter a) }.
```

I try this code to cast element of `A` to `subsetA` when `filter` passes, but failed to convenience Coq that it is a valid construction for an element of 'sig' type:

```
Definition cast (a: A) : option subsetA :=
match (filter a) with
 | true => Some (exist _ a (IstrueB (filter a)))
 | false => None
end.
```

Error:

```
In environment
a : A
The term "IstrueB (filter a)" has type "Prop"
while it is expected to have type "?P a"
(unable to find a well-typed instantiation for "?P": cannot ensure that
"A -> Type" is a subtype of "?X114@{__:=a} -> Prop").
```

So, Coq expects an actual proof of type `(IstrueB (filter a))`, but what I provide there is type `Prop`.

Could you shed some lights on how to provide such type? thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, there is the standard [`is_true`](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Init.Datatypes.html#is_true) wrapper. You can use it explicitly like so:

```
Definition subsetA : Set := {a : A | is_true (filter a) }.
```

or implicitly using the coercion mechanism:

```
Coercion is_true : bool >-> Sortclass.
Definition subsetA : Set := { a : A | filter a }.
```

Next, non-dependent pattern-mathching on `filter a` doesn't propagate `filter a = true` into the `true` branch. You have at least three options:

1. Use tactics to build your `cast` function:

   ```
   Definition cast (a: A) : option subsetA.
     destruct (filter a) eqn:prf.
     - exact (Some (exist _ a prf)).
     - exact None.
   Defined.
   ```
2. Use dependent pattern-matching explicitly (search for "convoy pattern" on Stackoverflow or in [CDPT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/)):

   ```
   Definition cast' (a: A) : option subsetA :=
     match (filter a) as fa return (filter a = fa -> option subsetA) with
     | true => fun prf => Some (exist _ a prf)
     | false => fun _ => None
     end eq_refl.
   ```
3. Use the `Program` facilities:

   ```
   Require Import Coq.Program.Program.

   Program Definition cast'' (a: A) : option subsetA :=
     match filter a with
     | true => Some (exist _ a _)
     | false => None
     end.
   ```

Comment: There is also `Is_true` in `Bool`.